# How to append path and filename to output

Tags: windows, search, cmd, dir

**Background**
I am searching a large directory for files with certian strings of characters in their names. I only want to know if the files exsist in said directory.

**Problem Description**
Right now I am inputing the following code into windows 7 cmd prompt

```
dir T162511*.dwg /s /b >> searchresults.txt 2>>&1
```

T162511.dwg is not found and the phrase "File Not Found" is inputted to a text file, also if you notice I am putting the found file with similar name's path of the files location in the text file as well provided that it was found.

**Question**
How can I get cmd prompt to output [Drive:]/Path/FileName.dwg and "File Not Found" to a text file in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir T162511*.dwg /s /b >> searchresults.txt 2>nul || (>>searchresults.txt echo T162511.dwg not found)
```

If dir command does not find the indicated file, it raises errorlevel and the code after `||` is executed

EDITED - Code adapted to comments. Assuming it will be included in a batch file, and the `drive:\path\to\file` is inside a variable (maybe defined from some parameters to batch file), this should to the work

```
set "filesToFind=c:\somewhere\T162511*.dwg"
dir /s /b /a-d "%filesToFind%"  >> searchresults.txt 2>nul || (>>searchresults.txt echo %filesToFind% not found)
```

Comment: This is close but it does not include the [drive:path] in fact if I run this for a random file and it doesn't find it it will output T162511.dwg i want it spit back to an output whatever file i put in it. Can you please respond with an answer.

Comment: Your edit worked however I changed it so that it would work as a search batch file. I appreciate your help.